# MS Access- Calculated Column for Distinct Count in Table Rather than a Query

Tags: ms-access-2010, calculated-columns, distinct-values

I'd like to have a Calculated Column in a table that counts the instances of a concatenation.

I get the following error when inputting `Abs(Count([concat]))` as the column formula for the calculation: `The expression Abs(Count([concat])) cannot be used in a calculated column.`

Is there any other way to do it without doing a query? I'm pretty sure it can't be done but I figured I'd ask anyways since I didn't see any other posts about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and even if there was, you should create and use a query for this.

Besides, applying *Abs* on a count doesn't make much sense, as the count cannot be negative.